# How do we compress the size of a base64 image in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, base64, image-compression

I receive a base64 encoded response from the api, which has huge no.of characters (data). So i want to scale/reduce the size of this base64 image. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: HTTP is commonly compressed already. you worry about nothing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Depends on what the purpose of that compression is. Maybe OP doesn't want to store huge huge images with high resolution in his database ... Then HTTP compression doesn't really help ...

Comment: blowing the data up as base64 does the **opposite** of help. whatever API does that should be re-engineered. at this point, we can't tell either way, because OP is being mysterious

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Exactly. We don't know anything about OP's use case. Thus telling OP, everything is alright because HTTP compression exists, isn't gonna help ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, base64 is just a text representation of some bytes.

First, you need to transform it into the buffer with bytes. E.g. like this:

```js
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(yourString, 'base64');
```

Then you should either save it on a disk and use some other tools like imagemagick to transform it:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('your-image.png', imageBuffer); // in case you know it's PNG, ofc
// transform somehow, probably invoking third-party tool using child_process.execSync
```

Or you may use libs like [Sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) to optimize the image in that buffer. Here's an example from the repo:

```js
sharp(inputBuffer)
  .resize(320, 240)
  .toFile('output.webp', (err, info) => { ... });
```

Depending on the type of the image you manipulate and on the transformations you're trying to do, you may need different tools, not only Sharp, but also Gifsicle or Guetzli.

Years ago my team created a small CLI tool for optimizing images for our needs. The tool does not solve your problem, but maybe its code, where we work with different encoders, can help you somehow:

https://github.com/funbox/optimizt/blob/master/lib/optimize.js

Answer (score 0):

Install library `npm install sharp`

Conversion to image, resize as you need, and then convert to base64

```
let arrData = `${imageBase64}`.split(',');
var imgBuffer = Buffer.from(arrData[1], 'base64');
const sharp = require('sharp');
let bufferImgCompressed = await sharp(imgBuffer)
.resize({ width: 100, height: 200 })
.toBuffer()
.then(data => { return data; })
.catch(err => { console.log('Error on compress'); });

let imgBase64Compressed = bufferImgCompressed.toString('base64');
```

The use of `${imageBase64}.split(',')` is because to convert base64 to buffer the string should not to contains the 'data:image/...'